# Mobile Chrome won't offer to scan Credit Card

Tags: html, google-chrome, autocomplete

We're setting up credit card autocomplete for our website. We have added autocomplete tags in HTML , such as `cc-number` for Credit card number field. However, when I tap on the credit card number field in mobile browser, Chrome does not offer to scan credit card. I've updated Chrome over Google Play 15 minutes ago, and I use Android 6. What could be the cause?

Answer (score 1):

Set of html attributes need to set for your text field,

type = "number", pattern="([0-9]{5})", inputmode="numeric"

And id or name attribute for the text field should read "CreditCardNumber" or label for your text field should read "Credit Card Number"